# Only jquery autocomplete download

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I want to download jquery autocomplete plugin, but it doesn't let me download only that file but with jquery core, jquery position, widget etc. scripts.
But I don't want all these files as I already have them added in my project and working fine, so I don't want to break any current working logic.

When I tried putting all the script came with autocomplete(including core.js), it worked but then my datepicker stopped working.

I also tried picking and adding only autocomplete script part from the full script but it didn't work, may be because I am using jquery 1.7.2 and I found autocomplete 1.10.2.

Is there any way to get only autocomplete plugin or any similar plugin that can work something like we get other plugins from outside authors?

Basically my requirement is not exactly of autocomplete, what I want is to have a text box that on focus show the list of options to choose, something like dropdownlist options but also lets us put our own value and don't show the dropdown list arrow.
I made this all working with the help of autocomplete plugin, the problem came when I tried adding it in my project.

Basically this requirement

[image]

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go to the [All jQuery UI Downloads page](http://jqueryui.com/download/all/) and get the file with the source.

Then, in the `ui` folder, you will see separate files for each module, including `jquery.ui.autocomplete.js`.

I do not know how your files are organized in your project, but be aware that the `autocomplete` module needs `core`, `widget`, `position` and `menu` in order to work. The first two must be loaded before `autocomplete`.

Your code should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-ui/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-ui/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-ui/js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-ui/js/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-ui/js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Thanks! That is helpful. But the new problem is I am using jquery 1.7.2 and the autocomplete I can find in the jquery site uses 1.9 versions function. I am getting error error that uniqueId function does not exist, menu.js file uses this function which is defined in jquery 1.9 but not in 1.7, any workaround for this?

Comment: @PawanNogariya Have you tried with the [1.9.0 version](http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.9.0.zip)?

Comment: Yes, it works with that. But I cannot use 1.9 version in my project as it can break older things.

Comment: I tried with jQuery 1.7.2 and the parts of jQuery UI 1.9.0 and I did not have any problem. Are you sure you used the files in [this link](http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.9.0.zip)?

Comment: Thanks man, that worked for me too now. I don't know why but some how core.css was preventing my jquery calendar working, I removed its reference and everything worked well!

Comment: Is there is any way to keep only autocomplete code in jquery-ui 1.12.1 in jquery-ui file? because custom file download not working on jquery ui site. any alternative way is most welcome. I am only commenting because I don't want to create duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to choose the right components to download
https://jqueryui.com/download/